# Multilingual article should display 404 when a translation is not available

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I setup Drupal 8 with 2 languages English & Arabic.
Now when an article (English for eg.) does not have a translation (in Arabic) and the user switches the language from the menu. The page loads in Arabic and the article loads in English. 
I need to return a 404 or something different.

Any advise would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can not be done using core or contrib

### To present 404 page not found (might create bad UX)

You could do something like this in your own module `MODULENAME.module` file

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view().
 */
function MODULENAME_entity_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  $lang = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage(LanguageInterface::TYPE_CONTENT)->getId();
  $type_id = $entity->getEntityTypeId();
  $translated = $entity->hasTranslation($lang);
  if ($type_id = "node" && $view_mode == "full" && !$translated) {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException();
  }
}
```

but once you go to the **not found page** the language switcher will not be able to take you back to the translated page though

### To Hide untranslated languages in language switcher

There is a [core issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2466553) about this and solutions are worked out but until it is solved you could create your own module

```
/**
 * @file
 * Hide language switcher links for untranslated languages on an entity.
 */
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_language_switch_links_alter().
 */
function MODULENAME_language_switch_links_alter(array &$links, $type, $path) {
  if ($entity = MODULENAME_get_page_entity()) {
    $new_links = array();
    foreach ($links as $lang_code => $link) {
      try {
        if ($entity->getTranslation($lang_code)->access('view')) {
          $new_links[$lang_code] = $link;
        }
      }
      catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        // This language is untranslated so do not add it to the links.
      }

    }
    $links = $new_links;

    // If we're left with less than 2 links, then there's nothing to switch.
    // Hide the language switcher.
    if (count($links) < 2) {
      $links = array();
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Retrieve the current page entity.
 *
 * @return Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityInterface
 *   The retrieved entity, or FALSE if none found.
 */
function MODULENAME_get_page_entity() {
  $params = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameters()->all();
  $entity = reset($params);
  if ($entity instanceof ContentEntityInterface) {
    return $entity;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Above solution is taken from [this post](https://www.drupal.org/node/2791231#comment-12004615)

### To Hide untranslated menu items

You can use [menu_multilingual](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_multilingual) which gives option when you create/edit a menu block to hide untraslated items.

Comment: Thank you @GiorgosK I've been banging my head against the issue for a whilst. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I'm going to keep working on it, but the first solution (which is the best so far) causes `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728` for different files. I'm debugging

Comment: I have tested it and worked, not sure why it would need more memory.  I suppose you have set your php memory to 128 which I would not recommend set it at least to 256MB (in your php.ini https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml)

Comment: So this is what I ended up with.
` $response = new RedirectResponse("/$lang");
    drupal_set_message(t('Page not found.'));
    $response->send();
    return;
`
Still can't print that message though